Jest Crashes When Importing JSON File with assert { type: 'json' }
This is my Jest configurations:
import type { Config } from 'jest'

const config: Config = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
}

export default config


And this is my typescript configuration in the tsconfig.ts:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2021",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "Node10",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*", "src/*"]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/utils/excelGenerator.ts", "src/__tests__/app.test.ts"],
  "files": ["src/types.d.ts"]
}

Log when I try to execute npm run test:

src/app.ts:6:50 - error TS2821: Import assertions are only supported
when the '--module' option is set to 'esnext', 'nodenext', or
'preserve'.
6 import swaggerFile from '../swagger-output.json' assert { type:
'json' };
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Test Suites: 2 failed, 2 total Tests:       0 total Snapshots:   0
total Time:        3.366 s Ran all test suites.


Please, provide tsconfig for completeness. The problem is what it says, "assert" is allowed in specific module targets, keeping it may require a more complex processing chain. I'd suggest to remove "assert" in case it doesn't affect how the app works because it's deprecated any way

Thank you for the suggestion. I have edited the post to show more details about the tsconfig. The code is in ESNext and requires the use of assert { type: "json" }.

The correct modern syntax is with { type: "json" }.. assert will be removed from javascript engines.

How do you run a test? There's a problem with the config, but I couldn't reproduce the error with it. What are package versions? Please, add package.json

The error describes the problem, TypeScript supports assert only for native ESM with specific target.
For Jest with native ESM, both extensionsToTreatAsEsm Jest option and  --experimental-vm-modules Node option have to be used, which is presumably done here. A certain TS config needs to be provided in Jest:
  '^.+\\.ts$': [
    'ts-jest',
    {
      tsconfig: {
        module: 'NodeNext',
        moduleResolution: 'Node16',
      },
    },
  ],

For Jest with CJS, which is more commonly occurring setup, this may require to add Babel to transforms to process compiled native ESMs further, no extensionsToTreatAsEsm option should be used. This requires jest-chain-transform, @babel/preset-env and @babel/plugin-syntax-import-attributes to be installed, with multiple Jest transforms being chained:
'^.+\\.ts$': [
  'jest-chain-transform', {
    transformers: [
      [
        'ts-jest',
        {
          tsconfig: {
            module: 'NodeNext',
            moduleResolution: 'Node16',
          },
        },
      ],

      ['babel-jest', {
        presets: [
          [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
              targets: { node: 'current' }
            }
          ]
        ],
        plugins: [
          [
            '@babel/plugin-syntax-import-attributes',
            { deprecatedAssertSyntax: true }
          ]
        ]
      }]
    ]
  }
],

Notice that assert has been deprecated in favour of with.
